# Postfixadmin doesnt see any mailbox or alias but mailboxes and aliases are in database

Tags: linux, email, postfix

Im migrating old mail server to iRedMail. After recreating mailboxes, admin, domains etc... in database on new iRedMail server I logged into postfixadmin and there was no mailbox or aliases ... All domains and domain admins are visible in postfixadmin, only mailboxes and aliases arent. :/ I have no idea why .... I was trying to change mysqld configuration but it didnt help. Mysql logs are empty and error log to :/ Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's correct.

When you create mail accounts, they are stored in MySQL, mailboxes are not created on file system.

When users login via POP3/IMAP, dovecot service will create mailboxes on file system for users automatically.

You can also post iRedMail related questions in its official forum: http://www.iredmail.org/forum/

Comment: but i recrecate file system also so there are all needed files...